# Terminate user session when the browser or tab closes

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

I want to ultimately have user sessions end once the browser or tab is closed, and so far i had no luck. I have tried to enable `offline_access` in the IdentityServer config and in the client config but that doesn't seem to help. I am seeking some help with having my setup function in this way.

I use the flow of SignIn that redirects you too the IS4 login page then upon successful login you get redirected to the client app.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I handle it: I'm using a JavaScript sessionStorage variable to sense when the user has closed the browser (or tab).

```
<script>
    var readValue = sessionStorage['checksession'];
</script>
```

If the browser was closed the variable will be undefined. In that case, I call a server-side page method to redirect the user to the login form:

```
<script>
    var readValue = sessionStorage['checksession'];
    if (readValue == null) {
    // Redirect to Login
    PageMethods.BrowserClosed();
    }
</script>
```

Server side page method must be static and marked as [WebMethod]:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void BrowserClosed()
{
    Util.hasClosedBrowser = true;
}
```

The static web method updates a boolean property in a static utility class (Util.cs) that I use in my asp.net project.

In Util.cs:

```
public static bool hasClosedBrowser { get; set; }
```

In the asp.net Page.Load event, I am looking for a "true" value in the "hasClosed" property defined in the utility class. If it's true, I call the Logout() method, which redirects to the login form:

```
if (Util.hasClosedBrowser)
{
    Logout();
    return;
}
```

At the end of the .aspx page after all of the elements, in a script tag I am setting the sessionStorage variable:

```
sessionStorage['checksession'] = "somevalue";
```

You can use any value in the sessionStorage cookie that you want, just know that it has to be a string unless you want to format it as a JSON string.

What's great about this approach is it correctly redirects to the Login form when the browser or the tab page was closed, but does not fire when the user simply refreshes the page (assuming the session hasn't actually expired). On a refresh, and as long as the session has not expired, the user's login state remains intact because the variable will still be present in sessionStorage.

Cheers,

-=Cameron

Comment: Great approach, i will try and adapt it to my solution.